# Google+ iOS SDK doesn't respond on delegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

Good day!
I'm trying to sign in via my custom button. And I use next code:

```
_signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
_signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, nil];
_signIn.clientID = kClientID;
_signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
_signIn.delegate = self;
[_signIn authenticate]
```

After tap, button opens G+ app or Safari\Chrome, asking for permissions and when I press "Ok", it just show the main page of G+ app (i.e). And method `- finishedWithAuth:error:` doesn't respond. It's look like this:

```
-(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"finished");
}
```

I already added `GPPSignInDelegate`, so I don't know what the problem is and how solve it.
And one more thing. I don't see my app at https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens . But I accepted it many times again and again.

Comment: hi could u post or share code, how u did google plus login using custom login and delegates. it would be thankfull to u

Comment: Hi, you can do this with `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` provided by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the handleUrl: from the delegate of your application.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance] handleUrl:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation: annotation];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In official docs was next code which I use: `- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation {
 return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                      annotation:annotation];
}` and it doesn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a URL type for your app?
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#step_4_add_a_url_type